# Accessing the currently displayed website of the Android browser

Tags: android, browser, caching

is it possible to programmatically access the website that is currently displayed within the Android browser?
As far as I know the native Browser doesn't handle plugins (please correct me if I'm wrong), so I thought that reading the browser cache would be an option.

Is there a more sophisticated way to get the currently displayed HTML?

Thanks in advance!
S.

Comment: The android browser can displays multiple windows, what would you want the result to be, all the currently opened windows or only the currently displayed window?

Comment: Well, I'd leave that to the user by asking which window to use if that is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to programmatically access the website that is currently displayed within the Android browser?

That would be a security violation, so, no. Also bear in mind that there are several Web browsers for Android.

> As far as I know the native Browser doesn't handle plugins (please correct me if I'm wrong)

The standard browser app supports plugins, but not ones downloaded on the fly. So, for example, it supports the Flash plugin (on Android 2.2+), but you have to install Flash separately first.

Comment: thanks so much. You accidentally have a link to a tutorial on how to develop such a plugin? :)